# DateTime Converting

Tags: c#, calendar, asp.net-4.0

I am trying to convert a string into a `DateTime` and change its format from `05/06/2012 12:00:00` to `2012-06-05 12:00:00.000` to search in the database (SQL Server 2008 R2) `DATETIME` column type. The original date is coming from a calendar!

I tried this:

```
string Datereturn = row.Cells[9].Text; 

DateTime dategiven = DateTime.ParseExact(Dategiven, 
             "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss[.nnn]", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

but it pops an error of invalid datetime

Comment: You should inspect the value of Datereturn to ensure it matches the format you are using as the parse template.

Comment: Also, the SQL Server DATETIME field will match any valid string date format (e.g. '05/06/12 12:00:00' and '2012-06-05 12:00:00.0000' are exactly equal DATETIME values)

Comment: You assign the value to Datereturn, but then parse Dategiven. Assuming that's a typo, what's the value of the string that gets parsed?

Comment: _The original date is coming from a calendar!_ then maybe `row.Cells[9].Value` already holds a DateTime?

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/710/helpzh.jpg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parse `05/06/2012 12:00:00`:

```
DateTime dategiven = DateTime.ParseExact(Dategiven, 
         "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

To get a different formatted string:

```
string newFormat = dateGive.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

I suggest reading [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) on MSDN.

Also the different between parsing and formatting (in regards to `DateTime`):

- Parsing means taking a string representing a datetime and getting a `DateTime` object from it
- Formatting a `DateTime` is taking a `DateTime` object and getting a string from it, formatted as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
DateTime dategiven = DateTime.ParseExact(Dategiven, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```